# osx, notification frameworks

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications

I'm looking to add notifications to my application. I thought about using [growl](http://growl.info/) but it looks like most everyone is pissed off at them from the comments and ratings on the mac app store. Based on [this](http://groups.google.com/group/growl-development/browse_thread/thread/0f48311507de8223#) thread I would also have to make my users to extra work to turn on/off the notifications.

Are there alternatives to growl? I would be happy witha framework that was self-contained, non-system wide. I'm just looking to say "display this information" and have it done. if 2-3 notifications come at the same time I'm looking for the framework to handle the display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, applications can still use the Growl framework, even if the user hasn't purchased the growl app from the store. 
You have to use something called the Mist framework, but it is all available on the Growl site.

http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php#sandboxinginyourapp

Will give you some more information.